# Change label.text from function Xcode/Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, label, selector

I have a timer, which calls a selector. 
Directly from that function, I want to change the text of a label.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update () {
self.myLabel.text = "MyNewText"
}
```

Xcode tells me to use "self", but the label is still not updating! 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UI updates must always be done in the main thread, so try this:

```
func update () {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.text = "MyNewText"
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you schedule the timer on the main queue/thread then the callback will also be called on the main queue/thread.